# Науки о языке

Tags: языкознание

Какие существуют науки о языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Фонетика**: изучает звуки речи и ударения.
**Орфография**: изучает правильное написание слов (то же, что грамматика и правописание).
**Лексика и фразеология**: изучает значение слов и словесных оборотов, выражений.
**Словообразование**: изучает структуру слов, их деление на части.
**Морфология**: изучает части речи и их формы.
**Синтаксис**: изучает состав предложения.
**Орфоэпия**: касается норм русского языка, правильного произношения слов, грамотного употребления слов и выражений.
**Пунктуация**: изучает знаки препинания.
**Стилистика**: изучает стили речи и их особенности.
**Этимология**: наука о происхождении слов.
**Топонимика**: изучает происхождение географических названий.

Answer (score 1):

Лингвстика (языкознние, языковдение; от лат. lingua — язык) — наука, изучающая языки. Это наука о естественном человеческом языке вообще и обо всех языках мира как индивидуальных его представителях. В широком смысле слова лингвистика подразделяется на научную и практическую. Чаще всего под лингвистикой подразумевается именно научная лингвистика. Является частью семиотики как науки о знаках.

Вопрос был задан о науках о языке, а не о его разделах.

Answer (score -1):

Никаких. Есть одна наука - правила русского языка. Является точной наукой, так как описывает знание непосредственно (отступление: считается, что математика является точной наукой, но как таковая может быть точной, если в ней используются условия в виде знаков? Математика входит в раздел обусловленные науки). 
 
Языкознание и языковедение - это вообще не науки, а части просвещения. Точнее, два раздела от красноречия. 

Вы же не говорите "наука об истории", "наука о математике", потому что история и есть - наука; математика и есть - наука. Русский язык - это уже наука (название науки).